# Chrome remote devices cannot debug WebView on mobile?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, adb, remote-debugging

Connected with mobile device via USB, open a WebView page. But no detected page list here. This issue was occasionally produced.

[image]

Comment: Can You try by running the command - `adb devices`. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to WebView debugging was banned by the host-app